# Xamarin lottie animation

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, lottie

I am trying to use Lottie to show animations, but I have a problem when I debug it for Android:

> LottieAnimationView not displayed because it is too large to fit into a software layer (or drawing cache), needs 9072000 bytes, only 8294400 available

My XAML code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <forms:AnimationView
        x:Name="AnimationView"
        Animation="data.json"
        AutoPlay="True" Loop="true"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Scale="0.2"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: How about this? https://github.com/martijn00/LottieXamarin/issues/105#issuecomment-348961708

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the export settings of the animation in AfterEffects, to fit the software layer limit

[image]